# Translate Laravel DB::raw() query with join to Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a Model 'Picture' (database table 'uploaded_pictures') that has many 'Like'(s)

```
private function likeWrapper() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'Like', 'typeId');
}

public function likes() {
    return $this->likeWrapper()->where( 'type', '=', Config::get( 'enums.content_types.PICTURE' ) )->get();
}
```

Now I want to create a page, paginated, that returns all Pictures ordered by the count of likes. I made this work using the Collection sortBy method:

```
$pictures = Picture::get()->sortByDesc( function($picture) {
        return $picture->likes()->count();
});
```

But this result can't be paginated. I have a raw query that does the job, but I struggle translate it to Eloquent query builder:

```
        $query = "SELECT p.*,  COUNT(l.id) AS countLikes
            FROM uploaded_pictures AS p
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (SELECT id, typeId, type FROM likes WHERE type='picture') AS l
            ON p.id = l.typeId
            WHERE  date<='$referenceDate'
            GROUP BY p.id, l.typeId
            ORDER BY countLikes DESC";

    $pictures = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

What is the equivalent of this query in Eloquent? I'm using Laravel 4.2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will work :

```
        $pictures = Picture::leftjoin('likes', 'pictures.id', '=', 'likes.typeId')
                    ->select(DB::raw('pictures.*, COUNT(likes.id) as countLikes'))
                    ->where('likes.type', '=', 'Picture')
                    ->orWhere('likes.typeId')
                    ->orderBy('countLikes', 'DESC')
                    ->groupBy('pictures.id')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Nope, the Picture attributes are completely missing. This translates to `select COUNT(*) as countLikes from 'uploaded_pictures' inner join 'likes' on 'uploaded_pictures'.'id' = 'likes'.'typeId' where 'likes'.'type' = ? group by 'uploaded_pictures'.'id' order by 'countLikes' desc limit 3`

Comment: Sorry I forget to add the select(DB::raw('pictures.*, COUNT(*) as countLikes')). I edited my post, I hope it's more that what you wanted

Comment: Yes, we're getting closer :) The last point is that the Pictures with no Like are missing